# Web Api returns status 500

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Writing a small MVC app that consumes a Web api I created and hosted on Azure. When I try call the method. it returns a status 500. I've tried fiddler to see what error is being returned but I don't get anything back

my client code

```
    public async Task<Planets> GetPlanets()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://newplanet.azurewebsites.net/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            // New code:
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/planet");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var listOfPlanets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Planets>(res);

                return listOfPlanets;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

my Service class,

```
    public class PlanetController : ApiController
{
    public IPlanetService _planetService;

    public PlanetController(IPlanetService planetService)
    {
        _planetService = planetService;
    }

    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public Planets Get()
    {
        var result = _planetService.GetPlanets();

        return result;
    }
}
```

I think the issue is with how I set up the web api config

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "api",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can you post MVC controller where you are calling GetPlanets

Comment: You should also check and make sure you're pointing to the correct server! I've gotten that problem in the past whenever we switched servers but people neglected telling me about it...lol

Comment: Are you using some DI container for injection?

Comment: Your API http://planetservice.azurewebsites.net/ is not working. Change your web.config - <system.web><customErrors mode="Off" /> then you can see error and stacktrace.

Comment: for some reason it stopped working. I've created a new service http://newplanet.azurewebsites.net/api/planet  updated the question with this aswell.

Comment: yes using Ninject, but should be ok. if you past the url into the browser it will pull it back. I just cant retrieve it from the MVC application.

Comment: Do you find solution and your code working ? I'm asking because your code is working for me

Comment: @BartoszCzerwonka, no, but now fiddler is showing that the api is returning 200 and when I'm debugging I'm I get to the call HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/planet"); but it never comes back. Maybe it has something to do with iis express. Cheers for your help

Comment: Ok, you can try run your project on local IIS not Express